# CMake VTK_DIR-NOTFOUND

Tags: cmake, vtk

VTK_DIR-NOTFOUND is returned when using CMake. I am using CMake GUI and, as other path errors, I can point then to proper path. However, for VTK doesn't work. I am pointing to directory where VTConfig.cmake file and others are. Also tried with all of other VTK dirs but without any sucess. I am using Visual Studio 12 2013 Win 64 configuration for generation but tried with 2010 too.

[image]

pointing to path manually,

[image]

Comment: Looks good, what you are doing. Just to be sure: Is the `ConfigVTK.cmake` in `lib/cmake/vtk-6.2`? What's your CMake version?

Comment: CMake version 3.4.3. and this directory contains cmake files as VTKConfig.cmake but not ConfigVTK.cmake as you suggest...

Comment: Sorry, I meant VTKConfig.cmake. I have no clue. Maybe run in debug mode and check what happens. Read some CMake code and compare.

Comment: Have you tried using `C:/Program Files/PCL 1.7.2/3rdParty/VTK` ?

Comment: Your VTK folder structure seems interesting... How did you receive this? Installed binaries or generated from the CMake? Also, are you sure the file you found is not VTKConfig.cmake.in. Typically, you find VTKConfig.cmake in the parent folder of bin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first thing I would check is what is the actual `find_package()` command being invoked where the error occurs? Perhaps that call is something a bit unusual or explicitly has the MODULE keyword (this would prevent the `VTKConfig.cmake` file from being found).

If that looks okay, check to see if something is modifying the VTK_DIR variable. Insert the following near the top of your top-most CMakeLists.txt file:

```
variable_watch(VTK_DIR)
```

This should tell you what, if anything, is modifying it in ways you didn't expect.

Assuming VTK_DIR is not actually being changed, the next thing you could try is setting `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` to the directory containing the `VTKConfig.cmake` file (you can add this in the CMake GUI if it isn't there already). Maybe also try `variable_watch(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH)` too just in case something is modifying that internally in unexpected was as well.

If that still doesn't reveal anything, then it would seem likely that there is something wrong with either your CMake or VTK installation. Perhaps try an earlier CMake version and see if you get any different behaviour.

Comment: How could I miss varable_watch?! Such an inferior tool compared to my current approach - printf debugging.

Answer (score 3):

Although the currently accepted answer is a good way of debugging, it looks like you're building Point Cloud Library (PCL) with the binaries from unancyowen. In which case I suggest ensuring your [system environment variables are setup correctly](http://www.nextofwindows.com/how-to-addedit-environment-variables-in-windows-7) which will automate the process you are currently going through and facilitate the job of the find_package() methods.
Assuming you installed everything in the same directory (i.e. where you have already linked to FLANN and Eigen) the following default PCL 3rd Party Libraries should be added to Path:

C:\Program Files\PCL 1.7.2\3rdParty\FLANN\bin

C:\Program Files\PCL 1.7.2\3rdParty\VTK\bin

C:\Program Files\PCL 1.7.2\3rdParty\Eigen

C:\Program Files\PCL 1.7.2\3rdParty\Boost

Then Qt, OpenNI etc. which are installed separately.

And you can also add:

BOOST_INCLUDEDIR : C:\Program Files\PCL 1.7.2\3rdParty\Boost\include\boost-X_XX\boost (Replace X_XX with your version number)

BOOST_LIBRARYDIR : C:\Program Files\PCL 1.7.2\3rdParty\Boost\lib

BOOST_ROOT : C:\Program Files\PCL 1.7.2\3rdParty\Boost

EIGEN_ROOT : C:\Program Files\PCL 1.7.2\3rdParty\Eigen

Answer (score 0):

In the field where it is showing that

> VTK - DIR : NOT FOUND

You can either copy paste the location or type in, or just browse for the file called `VTKConfig.cmake`. Generally found inside the build folder of VTK. This is how it solved in my case. Have a try!!